# Clojure map. Pass function multiple parameters

Tags: dictionary, collections, clojure, functional-programming

I'm looking for a way how to use map function in more custom way. If there is a different function for what I'm trying to achieve, could you please let me know this.

```
;lets say i have addOneToEach function working as bellow

(defn plusOne[singleInt]
   (+ 1 singleInt))

(defn addOneToEach[intCollection] ;[1 2 3 4]
   (map plusOne intCollection))   ;=>(2 3 4 5)

;But in a case I would want to customly define how much to add 

(defn plusX[singleInt x]
   (+ x singleInt))

(defn addXToEach[intCollection x] ;[1 2 3 4]
   ;how do I use plusX here inside map function?
   (map (plusX  ?x?) intCollection))   ;=>((+ 1 x) (+ 2 x) (+ 3 x) (+ 4 x))
```

I'm not looking for a function that adds x to each in the collection, but a way to pass extra arguments to the function that map is using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to go about it. One is using an explicit local function via `letfn`:

```
(defn add-x-to-each [ints x]
 (letfn [(plus-x [i]
           (+ i x))]
   (map plus-x ints)))
```

For this small piece of code this is probably overkill and you can simply streamline it via an anonymous function:

```
(defn add-x-to-each [ints x]
  (map #(+ % x) ints))
```

Both of these solutions basically apply the use of a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) which is an important concept to know: it boils down to defining a function dynamically which refers to a variable in the environment at the time the function was defined. Here we defer the creation of `plus-x` (or the anonymous) function until `x` is bound, so `plus-x` can refer to whatever value is passed in to `add-x-to-each`.

Answer (score 10):

another option to the already mentioned would be `partial` (note that in the example the order of the params does not matter, since you just add them, but partial binds them from left to right, so beware):

```
user=> (doc partial)
-------------------------
clojure.core/partial
([f] [f arg1] [f arg1 arg2] [f arg1 arg2 arg3] [f arg1 arg2 arg3 & more])
  Takes a function f and fewer than the normal arguments to f, and
  returns a fn that takes a variable number of additional args. When
  called, the returned function calls f with args + additional args.
nil
user=> (defn plus-x [x i] (+ x i))
#'user/plus-x
user=> (map (partial plus-x 5) [1 2 3])
(6 7 8)
```

Answer (score 5):

You almost got it right.

There are several possible ways:

1.

```
(defn addXToEach[intCollection x]
   (map #(plusX % x) intCollection))
```

`#(%)` means same as `(fn [x] (x))` (be aware that `x` is being evaluated here).

2.

```
(defn addXToEach[intCollection x]
   (map (fn [item] (plusX item x)) intCollection))
```

3.

```
(defn addXToEach[intCollection x]
   (map #(+ % x) intCollection))
```

and then you don't have to define your `plusX` function.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

You are applying `map` to *one* collection, so the function that `map` applies must take *one* argument. The question is, how is this function to be composed?

The function

```
(defn plusOne [singleInt]
   (+ 1 singleInt))
```

... works. It is otherwise known as `inc`.

But the function

```
(defn plusX [singleInt x]
   (+ x singleInt))
```

... doesn't work, because it takes two arguments. Given a number `x`, you want to return a *function* that adds x to its argument:

```
(defn plusX [x]
   (fn [singleInt] (+ x singleInt))
```

You can use a function returned by `plusX` in the `map`.

It is when you *compose* such a function that you can use extra arguments. This kind of function, composed as an expression involving captured data, is called a *closure*.

For example, `(plusX 3)` is a function that adds `3` to its argument.

```
(map (plusX 3) stuff)
;(4 5 6 7)
```

As you see, you don't need to name your closure.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for `+` the following will also work:

```
(map + (repeat 4) [3 4 9 0 2 8 1]) ;=> (7 8 13 4 6 12 5)
```

Of course, instead '4' put your number, or wrap with `(let [x 4] ...)` as suggested above.

It might not be the most performant, although, I guess.